# Inspecting console.log variables in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, console.log, web-inspector

As a thought, i would like to know if is possible to inspect for **log** properties of any variable in the chrome or any other browsers within the console mode. As i already know that you can already inspect the **DOM** in **inspector element** and you can go through debugging mode also. I want to demonstrate my point and why i and most novice would benefit this.

So as you can see in the picture below:
[image]

So as you can see i am trying to access some element of Array[15] but in the end it always giving me undefined. It nice just to test out some code before recompiling it again which takes time. Plus sometime you don't always knows enough that the function you are calling in JS is compatible with what you trying to achieve.

Comment: You have to wrap the individual array elements with jquery again to get access to the .attr method of jquery like this -

`$($('input')[0]).attr('class')`

Comment: Ahh that right... you code doesnt work. But it gave me more understanding. Anyway $('input') this only give me 1 element, i want an array. I try this $($('input')[0]) also but it didnt work

Comment: Just tried in the browser console. It worked for me. Not sure what you are trying to do but can you elaborate your use case so as to better understand your problem

Comment: Ahh yeah i found out i was trying to access iframe element which i havent referenced it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your entire code inside:

```
$(document).ready (function (){
    //Paste your code here
});
```

The whole point is you are trying to access an element in the DOM before it exists.

When your trying to access the class the item doesnot exist.

*Alternative:*
Move your script below the elements in the html.

This is a very generic solution I gave without seeing the code. Request you to post the code as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My function has been called and the array  was output from the angular controller. I guess i understand a little bit now

Comment: Then wrap it up in this function @Photonic: when you called the function and results in array , some of the elements are out of scope for the current class. I hope you can understand the code base and change the logic accordingly.

Comment: It turns out i was trying to access data from inside an iframe of which i didnt reference it. Thats why document.ready wasnt working for me

Comment: @Photonic: superb. Anything is good if it fulfills the requirement. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a debugger where you are outputting your array.  It seems to me you are trying to access the variable after execution is over, so the variable value is lost, as it goes out of scope.  When execution stops at the debugger, you can console.log your variable and properties.  At that point the variable will be in scope.

Comment: Thanks.. i litteral thought it wasnt possible to do what i was asking